# SML Date structure

Tags: datetime, sml, random-seed

I've been trying to figure out random number generation in SML. There's a standard library function that requires a fresh seed for each calculation

```
let
    val seed = Random.rand (123,456)
in
    List.tabulate(5, fn i => Random.randRange (1,100)  seed)
end

val it = [26,39,64,39,84] : int list
```

This works fine, but unless you update the `seed` with a new number pair each time, you get back the same random numbers. One way to get new numbers was found [here](https://www.smlnj.org/doc/FAQ/faq.txt), but this seems out of date, i.e., it doesn't seem to work -- or I'm just not using it correctly.

```
val seed = 
    let
        val Date.DATE(d) = Date.fromTime(Time.now())
        val m            = #minute d
        val s            = #second d
    in
        m,s)
    end

fun random (l,h) = Random.randRange (l,h) seed
```

Specifically, I can't get the

```
val Date.DATE(d) = Date.fromTime(Time.now())
```

to work. I've tried

```
- val Date.DATE(d) = Date.fromTimeLocal(Time.now());
```

but I get the error

```
stdIn:7392.1-7392.10 Error: unbound variable or constructor: DATE in path Date.DATE
stdIn:7392.1-7392.10 Error: variable found where constructor is required: Date.DATE
stdIn:7392.1-7392.12 Error: constant constructor applied to argument in pattern:bogus
```

This, however, works

```
- val mydate = Date.fromTimeLocal(Time.now())
val mydate =
:   DATE
:     {day=17,hour=22,isDst=SOME true,minute=27,month=Apr,
:      offset=SOME (TIME {usec=#}),second=3,wday=Fri,yday=107,year=2020}
:   : Date.date
```

but as a beginner, I don't really know how to extract anything from `mydate`. It seems the `Date.DATE(d) =` is supposed to "cast" the evaluation into the variable `d` which can be accessed by the record fields `#minute` and `#second`... Some explanation would be greatly appreciated. ([Here](https://smlfamily.github.io/Basis/date.html) is the `Date` structure.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FAQ is very out of date and seems to use a really old `Date` structure.

This works for me:

```
val seed = 
    let
        val d = Date.fromTimeLocal(Time.now())
        val m = Date.minute d
        val s = Date.second d
    in
        Random.rand (m,s)
    end;

fun random (l,h) = Random.randRange (l,h) seed;
```

Test:

```
- random (1,10);
val it = 7 : int
- random (1,10);
val it = 8 : int
- random (1,10);
val it = 7 : int
- random (1,10);
val it = 4 : int
- random (1,10);
val it = 3 : int
```

Comment: Yes, John Reppy confirmed. What you give was his basic suggestion, too. Good to get this on record.

Answer (score 1):

There was recently made another push towards making an SML package manager, [`smlpkg`](https://github.com/diku-dk/smlpkg).

One of the very few available packages is [`sml-random`](https://github.com/diku-dk/sml-random).

```
$ smlpkg add github.com/diku-dk/sml-random
```

Comment: Is there a SMLNJ version of the `smlpkg` executable?

Comment: If you read the second sentence of the first link I provide, "The package manager assumes nothing and knows nothing about the Standard ML compilers used and is thus quite generic."